# Opening a word document

Tags: vb.net

I have a add-in in word application to open a document form our company's portal.i have succedded to fetch the folders formt he portal and display them in the UI window.now i need to download the  document and open it and display.i have been told to use keys for a document.can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Grammar + spell check your question in said Word document :-)

Comment: You are coding a Word document add-in, that downloads a file from your company portal? Are the 'keys' you talk about, passwords?

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough here to provide a specific answer. There's all sorts of ways to pull documents from an unidentified "portal". FTP, HTTP Download, Webservices, etc etc. All those can be used from within a Word Addin. Basically, you pull the DOCX file down as a byte array, save it to disk, then tell word to open the file. Pretty straightforward.